# Need help understanding Nagios check_interval retry_interval max_check_attempts notification_interval notification_options

Tags: nagios

I need your help to understand the below directives timings in Nagios.

```
check_interval  
retry_interval  
max_check_attempts  
notification_interval  
notification_options
```

The email notification I am getting is not correct according to the timings; it is not constant as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

It makes me confused.

The first notification I received at 4:11 PM right after Nagios service restart, and later you can see there is no fixed interval.

- Question 1:  How to set email notification up at 10 minutes interval?
- Question 2:  At what time interval I should get emails in my inbox with down configuration?

My sample node.cfg:

```
define host {

    use                     linux-server            
    host_name               Linux_Slave
    alias                   Linux_Slave
    check_period            24x7
    check_command           check-host-alive
    check_interval          4
    retry_interval          1
    max_check_attempts      3
    notification_period     24x7
    notification_options    d
    notification_interval   5
    contact_groups          admins
    address                 x.x.x.x
}
```

Appreciate if any one of you can help me.

Comment: 1) change notification interval 2) every five time units (normally minutes, can be changed)

Answer (score 0):

from the emails extract you attached is not visible if the service got up and down again in the time between two notifications, that could help in understanding the actions taken by Nagios.

Could you check your Nagios logs for the precise event chain that led to the notification?

The emails are sent with the correct period, since you set `notification_interval   5`, i.e. the mail from 16:27 followed (after 5 minutes as expected) by a second mail at 16:32, and same goes for the mails from 16:47 and 16:52.

Technically, when an event happens that triggers an email (after 3 failed check attempts), you will receive a first notification, and then a new mail every 5 minutes, while the checks after the host/service is in an hard state are scheduled again with the normal check time.

Some infos about the checks timing can be also found at: https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/checkscheduling.html

Comment: Thanks for your time and advise. The host was completely down, it is actually my test machine and kept it off for the testing. I understand I should get first notification immediately and then at 5 minutes interval but notification received on 4:32 4:39 and 4:47 make me worried. Actually, I tried different timings first few notification I receive on exact notification_interval and then it automatically increases the time and then back to normal and again something happens like the time I mentioned above in this reply. I want to understand this.